# Find extremal values while plotting

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I have a parametric function `{x[t],y[t]}`. I then do

```
xArgMax = NArgMax[{x[t], y[t]>= 0, 0<= t <=1}, t]
{xx,yx} = {x[xArgMax], y[xArgMax]}.
```

I do the symmetric thing for `y`, to get `{xy,yy}`. The thing is that I will `Plot[{x[t],y[t]}, {t,0,1}]` later on, so it seems it would be efficient to find `{{xx,yx},{xy,yy}}` while gathering data points for the plot. Is there a utility for this? I know that `Plot[-args-][[1]]` contains lots of coordinates for the visual representation.

I want to eventually put this all into a `Manipulate`, so I need as much efficiency as possible.

EDIT: both `x` and `y` have the form

```
u[a,b][t] = [a t^b + (1-a) (1-t^.8)^(b/.8) ]^(1/b)
```

where they vary in parameters. Typical parameters are `.5,.5` for `x` and, say, `.3,1` for `y`. The differential approach can't help because typically the solutions will be on the boundary.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like:

```
f = 6 + # Sin[# + Pi] -  Cos[Pi #/4] &;
g = # Cos[# + Pi/3]/2 - 1/12 Sin[Pi #] &;

Plot[{f[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Mesh -> {{0}, {0}},
 MeshFunctions -> {ConditionalExpression[f'[#], f''[#] < 0 && g[#] > 0] &,
       ConditionalExpression[g'[#], g''[#] < 0 && f[#] > 0] &},
 MeshStyle -> {Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], Directive[PointSize[Large], Blue]},
 PlotLegends -> {Style["f", Red, 14], Style["g", Blue, 14]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cases[Normal@plt, Point[x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

> {{4.8209, 11.5918}, {4.8209, 2.16128},
>       {5.43663, 10.5002}, {5.43663, 2.74547}}

Versus direct computation:

```
xArgMax = NArgMax[{f[t], g[t] >= 0, 0 <= t <= 3 Pi}, t];
yArgMax = NArgMax[{g[t], f[t] >= 0, 0 <= t <= 3 Pi}, t];

{xArgMax, #@xArgMax} & /@ {f, g}
```

> {{4.8209, 11.5918}, {4.8209, 2.16131}}

```
{yArgMax, #@yArgMax} & /@ {f, g}
```

> {{5.43663, 10.5002}, {5.43663, 2.74547}}

Comment: ... this will mark all local maxima satisfying the conditions, not only the global maxima for the two functions.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know about MeshFunctions. Unfortunately, I can't use this approach, and my reputation isn't high enough to mark your answer as "useful".

Comment: As I mentioned in the new edit, for many parameter values, the extremal values will be found at the boundary. Thus, the derivatives are uninformative. Sorry, I should have given an example for x and y with my initial question.

Answer (score 3):

As example functions I'll use

```
x[t_] := (0.5 (1 - t^0.8)^0.625 + 0.5 t^0.5)^2
y[t_] := (0.7 (1 - t^0.8)^0.125 + 0.3 t^0.1)^10
```

To get the points that were calculated while plotting, one can use `Reap` and `Sow`.

```
{plot, {tValues, xValues, yValues}} = 
  Reap@ParametricPlot[{Sow[x[Sow[t, "t"]], "x"], Sow[y[t], "y"]}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Because `ParametricPlot` does some evaluations before the final plotting 
points are produced, one has to remove these pre-evaluations.

```
tValues = Drop[tValues, 4];
xValues = Drop[xValues, 4];
yValues = Drop[yValues, 3];
```

The different maxima based on the plotting points are

```
xtMax = Transpose[{tValues, xValues}][[Ordering[xValues, -1][[1]]]]
ytMax = Transpose[{tValues, yValues}][[Ordering[yValues, -1][[1]]]]
yxMax = Transpose[{xValues, yValues}][[Ordering[yValues, -1][[1]]]]
xyMax = Transpose[{yValues, xValues}][[Ordering[xValues, -1][[1]]]]
```

> ```
> {0.420465, 0.420448}
> {0.199283, 0.472206}
> {0.399565, 0.472206}
> {0.420442, 0.420448}
> ```

This information can be used for the starting values to find a more precise local maximum.

```
max = FindMaximum[{Max[x[t], y[t]]}, {t, First@ytMax, First@xtMax}]
```

> `{0.472206, {t -> 0.199335}}`

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[Transpose[{xValues, yValues}], PlotStyle -> Black],
  plot,
  Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Orange, Point[yxMax], Orange, Point[xyMax], 
   PointSize[0.01], Red, Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. Rest@max]}]}]
```

[image: Show]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{tValues, xValues}], Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[xtMax]}]
```

[image: xt]

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{tValues, yValues}], Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[ytMax]}]
```

[image: yt]

Answer (score 1):

So I found a method that might be of interest, but i'm not sure it's optimal.

```
rawPlotData =  ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 1}][[1]]; (* get plot data *)
plotData = Apply[List, rawPlotData[[1, 3, 2]]][[1]];
```

Index (1,3,2) of `rawPlotData` has a `Line[-data-]` object where `-data-` contains all the points. I don't know if this is the address for all Plot-type objects. Apparently if you use `Cases` you can search for the `Line` object directly.

```
{xOpt, yOpt} =  Flatten[Ordering[plotData[[All, #]], -1] & /@ {1, 2}];
{xx, xy} = plotData[[xOpt]]
{xy, yy} = plotData[[yOpt]]
```

This gets me what I need to put into Manipulate. However, I would think that `plotData` would be a useful input to `NArgMax` to speed the search for a more precise answer.